# Generating function: number of partitions that add up to at most $n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

> Find a generating function $a_n$, the number of partitions that add up to at most $n$.

So I know that if it were asking the number of partitions of the integer $n$, I would have my generating function as

$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots}
$$

But for now, all I can come up with to handle the "at most" condition is
$$
\prod_{r=1}^{m\leq n} \frac{1}{1-x^r}, \text{ for some } m.
$$
And I really don't think that this is correct. (No solution provided).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Start with your generating function for $p(n)$:

$$g(x)=\prod_{n\ge 1}\frac1{1-x^n}\;.$$

You want cumulative sums:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^np(k)\;.$$

Therefore you want to convolve the sequence $\langle p(n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ with the constant $1$ sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\dots\rangle$, whose generating function is

$$f(x)=\frac1{1-x}\;.$$

What is the generating function of that convolution in terms of $g$ and $f$?

Comment: Is it just $f\cdot g?$ I don't understand why it is if this is the case.

Comment: @Alan: Assuming that you mean the product, making it $$\frac1{1-x}\prod_{n\ge 1}\frac1{1-x^n}\;,$$ yes. Can you pin down what part you don’t understand?

Comment: Yeah, I meant product. I don't understand why that changes the number of partitions of the integer $n$ to number of partitions that add up to at most $n$. I guess I don't understand the convolution part. The only time I've been introduced to that was in differential equations.

Comment: @Alan: The coefficient of $x^n$ in the product $$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\right)$$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;.$$ If each $b_k=1$, this is just $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k\;,$$ giving you the cumulative total of the $a_k$’s.